# navigation on null route parameters ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-navigation

I wrote a navigation  and it works correctly.
If I view my page with `categoryId 20` then  navigator works ok, 
but I want it also to work if `null` passed for `CategoryId`. I show what I expect in comment.

```
'navigation' => array(

    'default' => array(
        array(
            'label' => 'Home',
            'route' => 'home',
        ),
        array(
            'label' => 'advertiseSearch',
            'route' => 'locate',
            'pages' => array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'advertiseCategorySelect',
                    'route' => 'locate',
                    'params'=>array(
                        'CategoryId'=>'20',// i want 'CategoryId'=>'' or 'CategoryId'=>null
                    )
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

What should I write so that even if `CategoryId` is not set, the navigator works?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried not setting the `params` key?

Comment: @guessimtoolate i want to say if specific paramas is null navigation is difference cause i have 4 parameters is route segments